# Migrating DB2 Blob/Rowid data types to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, db2-zos

How would I create the following DB2 table in PostgreSQL?

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
        idDoc       DECIMAL(15) NOT NULL,
        rowId       ROWID NOT NULL,
        checksumDoc DECIMAL(15) NOT NULL,
        doc         BLOB NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (idDoc)
    );
```

I came up with the following DDL for PostgreSQL, is this correct?

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
        idDoc       DECIMAL(15) NOT NULL,
        checksumDoc DECIMAL(15) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        doc         bytea NOT NULL DEFAULT E'\\000'
    );
```

Can I omit the ROWID?

Comment: So what are you storing in there?

Comment: Mostly PDF documents. And I would like to change the least possible, since it should be a one to one migration.

Comment: In a `ROWID`???

Comment: No, in the BLOB field. Sorry didn't notice that you were referencing to the ROWID column. In the ROWID column is something like an OID identifier for the Blob column in DB2.

Comment: Then it seems you don't need that column. A somewhat similar concept would be a "large object" in Postgres which also only stores a "pointer" - but then you wouldn't need the `bytea` column.